# What is the correct way to use fromIntegral to convert an Integer to real-fractional types?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to use fromIntegral to convert from Integer to a real-fractional type. The idea is to have a helper method to later be used for the comparison between two instances of a Fraction (whether they are the same).

I have read some of the documentation related to:

```
fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b
realToFrac :: (Real a, Fractional b) => a -> b
```

Where I am having trouble is taking the concept and make an implementation of the helper method that takes a Num data type with fractions (numerator and denominator) and returns what I think is a real-fractional type value. Here is what I have been able to do so far:

```
data Num = Fraction {numerator :: Integer, denominator :: Integer}

helper :: Num -> Fractional
helper (Fraction num denom) = realToFrac(num/denom)
```

Comment: You probably do not want to call your own data type `Num`, as this is the name of the main numerical _class_ (interface) in the Haskell library.

Comment: Unless you're doing this as an exercise, note that there already is a [`Rational`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-17.5/base-4.14.1.0/Data-Ratio.html#t:Rational) type in the base library that defines equality and allows conversion to any `Fractional` type (including `Double`) via [`fromRational`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-17.5/base-4.14.1.0/Prelude.html#v:fromRational).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to learn about the difference between *types* and *type classes*. In OO languages, both are kind of the same concept, but in Haskell they're not.

- A type contains concrete values. E.g. the type `Bool` contains the value `True`.
- A class contains *types*. E.g. the `Ord` class doesn't contain any values, but it does contain the types which contain values that can be compared.

In case of numbers in Haskell it's a bit confusing that you can't really tell from the name whether you're dealing with a type or a class. [`Fractional`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Fractional) is a class, whereas [`Rational`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Rational) is a type (which is an instance of `Fractional`, but so is e.g. `Float`).

In your example... first let's give that type a better name

```
data MyRational = Fraction {numerator :: Integer, denominator :: Integer}
```

...you have two possibilities what `helper` could actually do: convert to a concrete `Rational` value

```
helper' :: MyRational -> Rational
```

or a generic `Fractional`-type one

```
helper'' :: Fractional r => MyRational -> r
```

The latter is strictly more general, because `Rational` is an instance of `Fractional` (i.e. you can in fact use `helper''` as a `MyRational -> Rational` function, but also as a `MyRational -> Double` function).

In either case,

```
helper (Fraction num denom) = realToFrac(num/denom)
```

does not work because you're trying to carry out the division on integer values and only then converting the result. Instead, you need to convert the integers to something fractional and then carry out the division in that type.

Comment: Thanks, I was confusing Fractional with a type. And, I wasn't sure what would be the resulting type. However, Rational type works perfect.